# What does "step right on in anytime" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've come across it in the sixth episode of the fourth season of the TV series *Better Call Saul*. The context is that James comes into his former office, which is a small room inside a nail salon, where he hasn't been in a long time and with a bunch of phones. His landlord is really surprised.

> Landlord: What are you doing?
>
> James: Mrs. Nguyen.
>
> Just, you know, **step right on in anytime**, you know?
>
> Landlord: What's all this (pointing to the phones)?
>
> James: It's a side business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase

> Just, you know, step right on in anytime, you know?

is a chatty (informal), very cordial invitation for someone to come into a house or room.
It means "you are welcome to enter at any time".

In this example, it sounds as if it is being used very sarcastically, to express anger that someone has already entered without asking first.